# FOR loop won't complete when endval is a vector

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I have a for loop that works fine when

```
n=20 

for (i = 1: i + 1: n - 1)
    disp(['Iteration count =' num2str(i)])
    x = p + (i * h);
    fAdd = f(x);
    fNew = fOld + fAdd;
    disp(['fNew = ' num2str(fNew)])
    fOld = fNew;
end
```

but when

```
n = [20 40];
```

The loop stops after 20 iterations only and is missing 20 further fNew values for when n=40. Or when

```
n = [40 20]
```

The loop stops at 40 iterations but I dont want the extra 20 fNew values for when n=20
Is there any, and I mean any, way around this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the `for` loop to go to 40 but a small piece of the codes only runs up to i=20? You could have an `if` statement that lets certain parts of the codes to be evaluated when `i <= 20`. Something like the following?

```
for i = 1:n
    disp(['Iteration count =' num2str(i)])
    if (i <= 20)
        x = p + (i * h);
        fAdd = f(x);
        fNew = fOld + fAdd;
        disp(['fNew = ' num2str(fNew)])
        fOld = fNew;
    end
end
```